# Nginx config to serve react app from sub-folder

Tags: reactjs, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a create-react-app that I built, created `npm run dist` and copied the resulting dist files to `/var/www/html/build/`

Here is my nginx config:

```
server{
    listen 9095;
    server_name <hostname>;

    access_log     /var/log/nginx/nginx.pass.access.log;
    error_log      /var/log/nginx/nginx.pass.error.log;

    root /var/www/html/build/;
   
    location / {
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

With this, I can access `http://hostname:9095`.

What I actually need is to serve the same site with `http://hostname:9095/pass` (or `/PASS`) (and not `/`)

I have tried various re-write config but I can't seem to figure this out.. Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [format of a rewrite expression](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) is `rewrite <regex> <replacement> [flag];`. The simplest way to redirect `/pass` or `/PASS` to your `/var/www/html/build/index.html` page is as follows.

```
location ~* ^/pass$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.html break;
    root /var/www/html/build;
    index index.html;
}
```

The `location ~* ^/pass` directive is a case-insensitive regular expression match against the `/pass` URI. The `^` symbol ensures the regex matches only the `/pass` uri, and not something like `/some/dir/pass`, while the `$` symbol ensures a url like `/password` is not matched as well.

Note, however, that this regex will match `/pAsS`, `/PAss`, and `/pasS`. In other words, it really is case-insensitive. If you wish to match only `/pass` or `/PASS`, you should modify the regex accordingly.

Better yet, you can completely circumvent regex URI matching by using an exact URI match.

```
location = /pass {
    ...
}
```

Using an exact match like this [speeds up request processing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) because regular expressions do not need to be parsed.

To match `/PASS`, you could then simply define another exact location match block.

```
location = /PASS {
    ...
}
```

This then frees up your main location block for your primary server content.

```
location / {
    root /var/somewhere/else;
    index index.html;
}
```

Edit: After writing this, I came across the `alias` directive, which also seems promising. I haven't used it myself (I've always used rewrites for this kind of thing), but it's something else to explore as well.